# Rounding a UIImage but making the outside of the circle transparent

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

currently I am rounding a UIImage using this code:

```
//round the image

    UIImageView *roundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:smallImage];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(roundView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundView.bounds
                                cornerRadius:roundView.frame.size.width/2] addClip];
    [smallImage drawInRect:roundView.bounds];
    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    smallImage = finalImage;

    //end round image


    self.thumbnailView.image=smallImage;
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(smallImage, self, nil, nil); //20kb
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This however makes the outside of the circle white so when I press down on the image (if it's being used as a UIButton) you can see it's a square image. Is there anyway to clip a UIImage into a circle but make the outside of it transparent? Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Comment: round the `UIImageView` as Ayan says. not the `UIImage`, it will hog up lot of memory.

Comment: This causes table scrolling to lag severely with many images.

Comment: NO it will not lag UITableView, are you doing this `[yourImageView.layer setCornerRadius:CGRectGetWidth(yourImageView.frame)/2];` ?

Comment: yes I was doing this, it's fine for a few images but my table has 4 per row. So with many images it just ruins the scrolling experience. That's why I am trying to create circular images instead of rounding the view.

Comment: Then your image must big images, try use thumb images, smaller images, that will help.

Comment: they are thumbnails 70*70

Answer (score 1):

You can set the corner radius of `UIImageView` to make it rounded like this:-

```
[yourImageView.layer setCornerRadius:CGRectGetWidth(yourImageView.frame)/2];
```

You can increase it to make it small.

Comment: I was doing that before but the problem is that doing that slows down a table when scrolling if using many images. Have to make the UIImage background transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you have two calls to end the image context in your snippet, anyhow, although in theory the context itself should already be transparent (as you are passing NO to the opaque parameter), but in case it isn't, you can always fill it with transparent pixels before clipping and drawing the image

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(roundView.bounds.size, NO, 0.f);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[UIColor clearColor] set];
CGContextFillRect(ctx, roundView.bounds);
[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:roundView.bounds
                            cornerRadius:roundView.frame.size.width/2] addClip];
[smallImage drawInRect:roundView.bounds];
UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I did try out both your code and the added fill code in a Swift playground and they seemed to produce similar results, so I am not convinced this will solve your issue, and it is possible that you have not shown us all of the code that could be manipulating the context.

PS! Passing 0 to the `scale` automatically uses the correct main screen scale for the context ;)

EDIT: Just realised, your button probably has a white background set, which you usually wouldn't see under the image, but you do now as the image is transparent...